# Springs of action

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction

> Clockwork mechanisms were the most advanced technology in the
>   seventeenth century. Hobbes believed that muscles and organs in the
>   body were the equivalent of these: he frequently wrote about the
>   **‘springs’ of action** and the ‘wheels’ that move us.

[A little history of philosophy - Nigel Warburton, Chapter X]

What does "Springs of action" mean in the context?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't particularly mean anything - it is a way of illustrating that he thought that our bodies worked on mechanical principles like those found in clockwork. The quotation marks around *springs* are showing that it is the word that Hobbes used, and it doesn't really form a proper phrase with the words around it. It just says that he spoke of springs as being involved in human action.

Comment: *Action* has most likely shifted in meaning slightly since then, but it's related. It's more that every action must be driven by something, and he characterised what drives our actions as *springs*. It's not describing any characteristic of the spring, but rather the purpose the springs serve.